# Can't scroll when opening excel

Tags: excel, vba

I have a blank document with some macros that is used to create other documents. However, when I open the blank one, I cannot scroll up or down the screen unless I click out of Excel and click back in, or double click into a cell and then exit it.

I have tried application.enableevents=True, application.screenupdating=True, application.enableanimations=True, but none of them seem to work. Any ideas on how to fix it?

When I saved the document as a standard .xlsx, the issue still was there. Couldn't scroll unless i selected a different window and came back to Excel, or double clicked into a cell.

The scroll bars are still there and they work, but not the scroll wheel. The wheel works in other Excel documents, just not this one.

Here is the document to see if you can figure it out (It is not a good idea to share files with active connections in them). Try to make a video of the problem or to describe it better.

Comment: What is the code within the Workbook_Open sub procedure?

Comment: There is no code in it.

Comment: @matt - you realize that sharing an Excel file with an active connection in it is not a good idea?

Answer (score 1):

You can 'force' the scroll area to be all the sheet.

```
Sub fix_scroll_area()
    ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.ScrollArea = ""
End Sub
```

Comment: That didn't do anything.

Comment: @matt What excel version is this? Did you installed this recently?

Comment: 2016. I just got the computer about 2 months ago, but it was used, so I am not sure when it was installed.

Answer (score 0):

In general, the scroll area could be set to something without using macros.
The simplest solution is to go to the properties of the VB Editor and to delete whatever stays at the ScrollArea place (see the white arrow):

[image]

If it is not this, then feel free to run this:

```
Sub TestMe
    With ActiveWindow 
        .DisplayHorizontalScrollBar = True 
        .DisplayVerticalScrollBar = True 
    End With 
End Sub
```

Comment: The scroll bar is there and I can click on it to scroll, but the scroll wheel won't work. The wheel works in other applications and other Excel documents, just not this one.

Comment: @matt - are you sure that there is no VBA in your worksheet? Like even in the `Sheet` and the `ThisWorkbook`? It sounds like you have something.

Comment: I went and saved it as a xlsx workbook, and the same problem is in the xlsx workbook. Absolutely no code.

Comment: @matt - checked this -> https://excelribbon.tips.net/T011838_Scroll_Wheel_Doesnt_Work_when_Editing.html

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, I just maximized the window that contains the code and this fixed the problem